# HeadlesUI Tailwind slide in from bottom cause rerender while including button with logic

Tags: javascript, next.js, headless-ui

Based on headlessui with nextjs I wanted to create modal that will display when user click on specific item to display more information about it. The problem start to show up while I include button with some onClick logic. It seems like the modal is pre-rendering twice while loading. If in the place of button I put just simple div or p tag with some text it stopped. Can anyone explain to me what such thing is happening ?

That's the code for the modal

```
interface DishModalProps {
  open: boolean;
  item: dishData;
  onClose: () => void;
}

function DishModal({ open, item, onClose }: DishModalProps) {
  const { photo, name, description, price } = item;

  return (
    <Transition.Root show={open} as={Fragment}>
      <Dialog as="div" className="relative z-10" onClose={onClose}>
        <Transition.Child
          as={Fragment}
          enter="ease-in-out duration-500"
          enterFrom="opacity-0"
          enterTo="opacity-100"
          leave="ease-in-out duration-500"
          leaveFrom="opacity-100"
          leaveTo="opacity-0"
        >
          <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-black bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity" />
        </Transition.Child>

        <div className="fixed w-full inset-0 overflow-hidden">
          <div className="absolute inset-0 overflow-hidden">
            <div className="fixed w-full h-3/5 overflow-hidden bottom-0">
              <Transition.Child
                as={Fragment}
                enter="transform transition ease-in-out duration-500 sm:duration-700"
                enterFrom="translate-y-full"
                enterTo="translate-y-0"
                leave="transform transition ease-in-out duration-500 sm:duration-700"
                leaveFrom="translate-y-0"
                leaveTo="translate-y-full"
              >
                <Dialog.Panel className="flex flex-col w-full h-full transform overflow-hidden rounded-t-xl bg-white text-left align-middle">
                  <Transition.Child
                    as={Fragment}
                    enter="ease-in-out duration-500"
                    enterFrom="opacity-0"
                    enterTo="opacity-100"
                    leave="ease-in-out duration-500"
                    leaveFrom="opacity-100"
                    leaveTo="opacity-0"
                  >
                    <div className="relative w-full">
                      <div className="absolute top-4 right-4">
                        <p>one two three</p>
                        {/* <button
                          // onClick={() => onClose}
                          className="bg-base-secondaryLight h-8 w-8 rounded-lg flex items-center justify-center"
                        >
                          <XMarkIcon className="w-4 h-4 stroke-[3px]" />
                        </button>
                      </div> */}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </Transition.Child>

                </Dialog.Panel>
              </Transition.Child>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Dialog>
    </Transition.Root>
  );
}

export default DishModal;
```

Comment: Seems like the issue is caused by button elements that is included inside the code. However when the button tag is changed into div then the problem disappear. Trying to figure it out why button might cause such issue..